# Format decimal to currency in @ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am calling a decimal thusly in my view:

```
@ViewBag.CalculatePrice
```

How can I format that to represent $xxx.xx?

CalculatePrice is just a `public decimal CalculatePrice() { //performing calculation }` in a class.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't really understand what is being asked here, how do you limit to two floating numbers? how to you add a `$` prefix? Anyway I don't think it is an `asp.net-mvc` or a `razor` question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicitly cast it to `decimal`; then you'll be able to treat it as though it were statically-typed.

```
@(((decimal)ViewBag.CalculatePrice).ToString("C2"))
```

If you were wondering how to specify formatting for a decimal, [here's a reference for .NET's standard numeric formatting strings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: Edit: I think "C2" is a little more what you're looking for.

Comment: It's already a decimal, so `@((ViewBag.CalculatePrice).ToString("C2"))` worked just fine. Thanks, couldn't get the formatting down.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just need to use Use String.Format. I'm confused because this seems a little too obvious to me.

Are you assigning ViewBag.CalculatePrice in your controller?

Comment: a little too nuanced for me, in fact. @JustinMorgan's answer was the way to go. I couldn't get the format down properly.